# Как перегрузить операторы для шаблонного класса?

Tags: c++, шаблоны-с++, операторы

Собственно задание:

Нужно написать класс описывающий обычный вектор на плоскости. Для этого класса вам нужно реализовать сложение, вычитание, умножение на число (слева и справа) и сравнение на равенство/неравенство. Все операторы должны быть реализованы как внешние функции. Короткие версии операторов реализовывать не нужно.

Кроме того нужно реализовать конструктор от Vector2D с другим шаблонным параметром. Т.е. должен корректно работать следующий код:

Vector2D v(1,2);
Vector2D w(v);

вроде все написал, но не могу корректно перегрузить операторы с использованием шаблонов.
Расскажите, пожалуйста, как.
Спасибо!

Естественно, например такой код не работает:
Vector2D v(1,2);
Vector2D res = v * 3;

но если нужно чтобы и он работал, то как перегрузить еще операторы не добавляю новых функций? Как закастовать переданный Vector2D в другой тип? (который требуется на выходе)

вот весь код класса:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>

using namespace std;

// шаблонный класс Vector2D
template <class T>
struct Vector2D
{
     Vector2D() { x = 0; y = 0; }
     Vector2D(T x, T y) : x(x), y(y) {}

     template <class V> Vector2D(V const& v) {
        x = (T) v.x;
        y = (T) v.y;
     }
public:
     T x;
     T y;
};

// оператор +
template <class T>
Vector2D<T> operator + (Vector2D<T> & a, Vector2D<T> const& b) {
    a.x = a.x + b.x;
    a.y = a.y + b.y;
    return a;
}

// оператор -
template <class T>
Vector2D<T> operator - (Vector2D<T> & a, Vector2D<T> const& b) {
    a.x = a.x - b.x;
    a.y = a.y - b.y;
    return a;
}

// оператор умножения на число слева
template <class T>
Vector2D<T> operator * (T k, Vector2D<T> & a) {
    a.x = a.x * k;
    a.y = a.y * k;
    return a;
}

// оператор умножения на число справа
template <class T>
Vector2D<T> operator * (Vector2D<T> & a, T k) {
    a.x = a.x * k;
    a.y = a.y * k;
    return a;
}
```

Сервер же выдает такую ошибку:

```
Compilation error
main.cpp: In instantiation of ‘void check_operations(double, double, double, double) [with T = int]’:
main.cpp:151:56:   required from here
main.cpp:145:23: error: no matching function for call to ‘operator+(VTest2D&, Vector2D&)’
     operator+(ta, b);
                       ^
main.cpp:145:23: note: candidates are:
main.cpp:29:13: note: template Vector2D operator+(Vector2D&, const Vector2D&)
 Vector2D operator + (Vector2D & a, Vector2D const& b) {
             ^
main.cpp:29:13: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
main.cpp:145:23: note:   cannot convert ‘ta’ (type ‘VTest2D’) to type ‘Vector2D&’
     operator+(ta, b);
                       ^
main.cpp:79:12: note: template VTest2D operator+(const VTest2D&, const VTest2D&)
 VTest2D operator+(VTest2D const& a, VTest2D const& b)
            ^
main.cpp:79:12: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
main.cpp:145:23: note:   cannot convert ‘b’ (type ‘Vector2D’) to type ‘const VTest2D&’
     operator+(ta, b);
                       ^
main.cpp:146:23: error: no matching function for call to ‘operator-(VTest2D&, Vector2D&)’
     operator-(ta, b);
                       ^
main.cpp:146:23: note: candidates are:
main.cpp:37:13: note: template Vector2D operator-(Vector2D&, const Vector2D&)
 Vector2D operator - (Vector2D & a, Vector2D const& b) {
             ^
main.cpp:37:13: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
main.cpp:146:23: note:   cannot convert ‘ta’ (type ‘VTest2D’) to type ‘Vector2D&’
     operator-(ta, b);
                       ^
main.cpp:85:12: note: template VTest2D operator-(const VTest2D&, const VTest2D&)
 VTest2D operator-(VTest2D const& a, VTest2D const& b)
            ^
main.cpp:85:12: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
main.cpp:146:23: note:   cannot convert ‘b’ (type ‘Vector2D’) to type ‘const VTest2D&’
     operator-(ta, b);
                       ^
main.cpp: In instantiation of ‘void check_operations(double, double, double, double) [with T = double]’:
main.cpp:152:56:   required from here
main.cpp:145:23: error: no matching function for call to ‘operator+(VTest2D&, Vector2D&)’
     operator+(ta, b);
                       ^
main.cpp:145:23: note: candidates are:
main.cpp:29:13: note: template Vector2D operator+(Vector2D&, const Vector2D&)
 Vector2D operator + (Vector2D & a, Vector2D const& b) {
             ^
main.cpp:29:13: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
main.cpp:145:23: note:   cannot convert ‘ta’ (type ‘VTest2D’) to type ‘Vector2D&’
     operator+(ta, b);
                       ^
main.cpp:79:12: note: template VTest2D operator+(const VTest2D&, const VTest2D&)
 VTest2D operator+(VTest2D const& a, VTest2D const& b)
            ^
main.cpp:79:12: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
main.cpp:145:23: note:   cannot convert ‘b’ (type ‘Vector2D’) to type ‘const VTest2D&’
     operator+(ta, b);
                       ^
main.cpp:146:23: error: no matching function for call to ‘operator-(VTest2D&, Vector2D&)’
     operator-(ta, b);
                       ^
main.cpp:146:23: note: candidates are:
main.cpp:37:13: note: template Vector2D operator-(Vector2D&, const Vector2D&)
 Vector2D operator - (Vector2D & a, Vector2D const& b) {
             ^
main.cpp:37:13: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
main.cpp:146:23: note:   cannot convert ‘ta’ (type ‘VTest2D’) to type ‘Vector2D&’
     operator-(ta, b);
                       ^
main.cpp:85:12: note: template VTest2D operator-(const VTest2D&, const VTest2D&)
 VTest2D operator-(VTest2D const& a, VTest2D const& b)
            ^
main.cpp:85:12: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
main.cpp:146:23: note:   cannot convert ‘b’ (type ‘Vector2D’) to type ‘const VTest2D&’
     operator-(ta, b);
                       ^
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Формулировка интересная. Что характерно у меня в VS2013 все компилируется нормально. Только код

```
Vector2D<double> v(1, 2); 
Vector2D<double> res = v * 3.0;
```

Для умножения лучше использовать

```
template <class T, class N> Vector2D<T> operator * (Vector2D<T> & a, N k)
```

Comment: Как у вас может компилироваться?! Вы, вообще-то, смотрели сообщения об ошибках в вопросе? Что у вас, например,  VTest2D?

Comment: int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
 Vector2D<double> a, b;
 a = a + b;
 Vector2D<double> v(1, 2); 
 Vector2D<double> res = v * 3.0;
 return 0;
} Что такое VTest2D я и сам бы хотел узнать

Comment: Не знаю, в том то и дело. Это сервер проверяет. Условие я выложил и мое решение вроде бы ему соответствует.
Не знаю в какую сторону копать

Comment: Где проверяется

Comment: на stepic.org, но это закрытое задание

Comment: Попробуй template <class T1, class T2, class T3> Vector2D<T1> operator + (Vector2D<T2> & a, Vector2D<T3> const& b)

Comment: а T1 зачем? Сейчас попробую

Comment: помимо прочего в простыне вывода появилось:

main.cpp:127:13: note:   couldn't deduce template parameter ‘T1’
     if ( (a + b) != (ta + tb) )                
             ^

Comment: template <class T1, class T2> Vector2D<T1> operator + (Vector2D<T1> & a, Vector2D<T2> const& b)

Comment: здесь ответ сервера (простыня): http://vk.com/doc71761993_437011357

Comment: а какое хоть в точности задание

Comment: вот здесь полностью задание и исх код:
http://vk.com/doc71761993_437011374

Comment: Глянь http://cpp.sh/2fr5

Comment: Мы с тобой строчку про проверку на равенство пропустили :)

Comment: Неужто заработало

Comment: нет)
все равно на оператор сложения ругается.

Comment: `template <class T1, class T2>`
`bool operator == (Vector2D<T1> const& a, Vector2D<T2> const& b) {`
    `    if (a.x == (T1)b.x && a.y==(T1)b.y ) {`
   `             return true;`
   `     } else {`
  `          return false;`
 `       }`
`}`

Comment: вот так оператор сравнения реализовал. Но сомневаюсь в приведении типов, да и он что то не работает на вывод

Comment: template <class T, class V>
bool operator == (Vector2D<T>  a, Vector2D<V>  b) {
    return (a.x==b.x) && (b.x==b.y);
}

Comment: если мы даблы с интом будем сравнивать, они ж никогда равными не будут.. это вообще можно делать без привидения?

впрочем все равно compilation error

Comment: есть такая вещь как автопривидение встроенных классов типа double a=2; Но можно написать и a.x==T(b.x)

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/31261/discussion-between---and-evgeny-shmidt).

Comment: решил) проблема была с неправильным приведением и отсутствием конст ссылок